# Send characters to console application

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I have simple console application that runs in terminal window reads and prints character:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    while (true)
    {
        char c =getchar();
        printf("%c \n",c);

    }

}
```

Now I would like to make test application that could emulate character press in first application terminal.

Which way I should go? What API functions I should use for this purpose?

Comment: Just send the data to the stdin of your application.

Comment: Do you mean having another app that runs and sends any characters that you type to this apps output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for special APIs or whatever. Since your sample application is only reading from standard input, you can just send stuff to there.

Before running the program in a terminal, check its connected terminal using `tty` command. Then send data to that tty that `tty` reports.

Alternatively, grab the PID of your running application and send data to `/proc/$PID/fd/0` so you don't need to check for tty.

Comment: "Then send data to that tty that tty reports" - that will just print the data to that terminal, not provide it as input to the program. So will sending data to `/proc/$PID/fd/0` since that's connected to the tty.

Answer (score 0):

Just pipe the test data to your process:

```
echo "some test data" | ./myprogram
```

(Your example program in the question will read and print each letter from "some test data").

There are plenty of other variations on this. Read about the shell and shell pipelines.