# Eclipse console tty address

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I have simple console [programm that reads char and prints it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622055/send-characters-to-console-application/48622134#48622134).

I send test characters from another console:

```
echo a >> /dev/pts/7
```

And it works fine.

Now I need to debug this application in Eclipse IDE. How to know Eclipse's debug console tty address?

Comment: The Eclipse console doesn't work like that and doesn't have a tty address